# Diamond with questionmark in page item

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, special-characters, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm having a issue with special characters like ö, ä, etc..

My report column 'achternaam' has the value:
Schr��der  while it needs to be Schröder
[image]

**Classic report - select:**

```
WITH  voorstel  as (
  SELECT rownum i, vrstl.voornaam, vrstl.achternaam, vrstl.voorvoegsels, vrstl.rol
    from XMLTABLE (
      '/json/row'
      PASSING apex_json.to_xmltype( V('P4084_API_RESPONSE') ) 
      COLUMNS
       volg_nr VARCHAR(20) PATH 'Volg_nr',
       voornaam VARCHAR(20)  PATH 'Voornaam',
       voorvoegsels VARCHAR(20) PATH 'Voorvoegsel',
       rol VARCHAR(20) PATH 'Rol',
       achternaam  VARCHAR(25)  PATH 'Achternaam') as vrstl
  )
  select   voorstel.i
         , voorstel.voornaam
         , CONVERT(voorstel.achternaam, 'al32utf8', 'UTF8')  achternaam
         , voorstel.voorvoegsels
         , voorstel.rol
  from voorstel
```

**:P4084_API_RESPONSE:**

```
   [{"Volg_nr":1,"Rol":"AUT","Achternaam":"Busser","Voornaam":"Marianne"},
    {"Volg_nr":2,"Rol":"AUT","Achternaam":"Schröder","Voornaam":"Ron"},
    {"Volg_nr":3,"Rol":"ILL","Achternaam":"Stam","Voornaam":"Dagmar"}]
```

**NLS_DB_PARAMETERS**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is an option on the specific column to not escape special characters.  Have you tried that?

I would say try the above (if you haven't) without and with the conversion.

`CONVERT(voorstel.achternaam, 'al32utf8', 'UTF8')`